# Loop each folder and subfolder to get values

Tags: vba

Any tips or improvement to speed my code? I'm looping each file in the specify folder and subfolders. I will open each file and get the values I need and copy it to my activesheet. It is taking quit some time, any tips to help?

```
FolderName = InputBox("Enter path", "Get File")

Dim fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, oFile, queue As Collection

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set queue = New Collection
queue.Add fso.GetFolder(FolderName)

Do While queue.Count > 0
    Set oFolder = queue(1)
    queue.Remove 1 'dequeue
    For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
        If UCase(oSubfolder.Name) <> "DO NOT USE" Then
            queue.Add oSubfolder 'enqueue
        Else
        End If
    Next oSubfolder
    Dim lastUsedRow As Long
    lastUsedRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        'Process each file but exclude files such as "~xxxxxx" or thumbs.db or xxxx.tmp files
        If oFile.Type = "Microsoft Excel Worksheet" Then
            If Not oFile.Name Like "*~*" Then                    
                Dim app As New Excel.Application
                Dim Filename As String
                Filename = oFile.Path
                app.Visible = False 'Visible is False by default, so this isn't necessary
                Dim book As Excel.Workbook
                Set book = app.Workbooks.Add(Filename)
                ActiveSheet.Range("A" & lastUsedRow) = oFile.Name
                ActiveSheet.Range("B" & lastUsedRow) = oFile.DateCreated
                ActiveSheet.Range("E" & lastUsedRow) = book.Sheets("mySheet").Range("D3").Value
                ActiveSheet.Range("F" & lastUsedRow) = book.Sheets("mySheet").Range("G12").Value
                ActiveSheet.Range("G" & lastUsedRow) = book.Sheets("mySheet").Range("C9").Value
                ActiveSheet.Range("H" & lastUsedRow) = book.Sheets("mySheet").Range("C13").Value
                book.Close SaveChanges:=False
                app.Quit
                Set app = Nothing
                lastUsedRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next oFile
Loop
```

Comment: Other than some minor tweaks like `With` blocks, I doubt you're going to speed this up much - you're opening files so this is largely IO bound.

Comment: You're creating a new `Excel.Application` instance for each file in the folder, as well as a new file altogether... is that intended? In any case, the `app` instance should be pulled out of the loop, and if the code is hosted in Excel then there's no need to even create an instance of it. `As New` is also interfering with the `=Nothing` assignment at the end.

Comment: Depends what you need to do, but as a rule of thumb I see no need to re-instantiate Excel *for every single file you want to process* when you're already in Excel.

Comment: Welcome To Code Review! I have rolled back your last edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mathieu Guindon mentioned in the comments, the main slow down is that you are creating a new Excel.Application for each file.   I would personally just use the current Application and turn off `Application.ScreenUpdating`.

Using an `InputBox` to prompt an user to enter a folder path is very prone to error. You should test if the folder exists.

> ```
> FolderName = InputBox("Enter path", "Get File")
> Do While Len(Dir(FolderName, vbDirectory)) = 0
>     If Len(Dir(FolderName, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
>         If MsgBox("Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo, "Invalid Folder") <> vbYes Then
>             Exit Sub
>         Else
>             FolderName = InputBox("Enter path", "Get File")
>         End If
>     End If
> Loop
> ```

Or better yet just use `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)` to pick the folder.  It's the right tool for the job.

Using an Array to collect the data and writing it to a range of cells in one operation is much faster the writing each piece of data to an individual cell.

### Refactored Code

Here is how I would write the code.  Notice that I created a subroutine to collect the files and another to get the Folder Path.  This allows me to debug each part of the code separately.

```
Sub LoopFoldersAndXLFiles()
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
    Const SheetName As Variant = 1
    Dim FileList As Collection
    addExcelFileList FileList
    If FileList.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Dim oFile As Object, xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim r As Long
    Dim results() As Variant
    ReDim results(1 To FileList.Count, 1 To 8)
    For r = 1 To FileList.Count
        Set oFile = FileList(r)
        With xlApp.Workbooks.Add(oFile.Path)
            results(r, 1) = oFile.Name
            results(r, 2) = oFile.DateCreated
            results(r, 5) = .Sheets(SheetName).Range("D3").Value
            results(r, 6) = .Sheets(SheetName).Range("G12").Value
            results(r, 7) = .Sheets(SheetName).Range("C9").Value
            results(r, 8) = .Sheets(SheetName).Range("C13").Value
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
    Next

    xlApp.Quit

    With ActiveSheet
        With .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            .Resize(UBound(results), UBound(results, 2)).Value = results
        End With
    End With
    Debug.Print Round(Timer - t, 2)
End Sub

Sub addExcelFileList(ByRef FileList As Collection, Optional FolderName As String, Optional fso As Object)
    If Len(FolderName) = 0 Then
        FolderName = getFolderPath
        If Len(FolderName) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    End If
    If FileList Is Nothing Then Set FileList = New Collection
    If fso Is Nothing Then Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim oFolder As Object, oSubfolder As Object

    Set oFolder = fso.GetFolder(FolderName)

    For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
        If UCase(oSubfolder.Name) <> "DO NOT USE" Then addExcelFileList FileList, oSubfolder.Path, fso
    Next

    Dim oFile As Object
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        If oFile.Type = "Microsoft Excel Worksheet" And Not oFile.Name Like "*~*" Then FileList.Add oFile
    Next
End Sub

Function getFolderPath() As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Function
        getFolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: this works but it's actually slower than what i have after I modified it to work. I will edit my post.